# How to activate sodium acetate hand warmer without the button?

Tags: substitute-tool, winter

I recently bought four hand warmers. Two work fine, but of the other two, the buttons are very difficult (or as of yet impossible) to click and don't active the solution.

Does anyone know a way to agitate the bags enough to get the solution to activate without the in-bag buttons?

**Update:** I went ahead a boiled the "duds" when I reset the ones that worked and that seemed to make the solution work much more easily.

Answer (score 7):

They just need a localised physical shock.
Try slapping with a wooden ruler, flat side on & not so hard that you burst it.

The clicker is a nucleation site, the shock waves start the reaction going. Once started, the rest will join in of its own accord.

Comment: I tried slamming it against a concrete floor, and that didn't work...

Comment: ...which is not the same thing.

Comment: You need a focused site, hit it with something with the least surface area and greatest force (while not breaking it.)